# JavaScript Class and Constructor (non-Dojo

Tags: javascript, class

```
var TreeNode = function() {

  this.x    =       null;       
  this.y    =       null;
  this.data =       [];

  TreeNode = function(x1,y1,object) {
    this.x = x1;
    this.y = y1;
    this.data.push(object);
  };

};
```

My Problem is that if I make new `TreeNode(90,80,"Hallo World");` it tells me that this.data is undefined. Can anyone help me?

Greetings

Comment: What're you trying to achieve? You're defining 2 `TreeNode` constructors here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create data before push :

```
TreeNode = function(x1,y1,object) {
    this.data = [];
    this.x = x1;
    this.y = y1;
    this.data.push(object);
};
```

Comment: How about `this.data = [object];`? You won't need the `.push(object)` there. Also, don't use `.push()`. Use `.length` (e.g.: `this.data[this.data.length] = object;`), which is faster than the `.push()` method.

Comment: Thank's for your comment, it seems to be a good idea : I simply get it run, it's better to get it run and optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var TreeNode  = function(x1,y1,object)
    {
        this.data = [];
        this.x = x1;
        this.y = y1;
        this.data.push(object);
    };

var treeNode = new TreeNode(1,2, 'node data');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve from your question, but the following does work without issue:

```
function TreeNode (x ,y, obj) {    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.data = [obj];
}

var aTreeNode = new TreeNode(1, 2, 'hello world');
console.log(aTreeNode.data);  //['hello world']
```

From your code above, it looks like you're creating 2 `TreeNode` constructors - one inside the other. Is this intentional?

Comment: No I am defining a Class. In C++ the constructor has the same name as the class itself

Comment: JavaScript is not C++. JavaScript itself **does not** contain classes, but similar functionality can be achieved by using functions and prototypical inheritance. I suggest expanding your knowledge on the subject first. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) is a good place to start!

Comment: ES6 contains classes. But I agree that this is the best way.